# Can I use ng-repeat items by two each time in angularJS v1?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-scope

So I'm having quite a bit a trouble putting two array items inside a div tag using ng-repeat. Tried a few things, but can't figure it out. Below you can see the layout I'm trying to achieve... Any help would be great!

```js
angular.module('starter', [])

.controller('PeopleCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.people = [

    {
      image: "https://placehold.it/350x150",
      dob: "23/06/1990"
    }, {
      image: "https://placehold.it/350x150",
      dob: "12/12/2000"
    }, {
      image: "https://placehold.it/350x150",
      dob: "12/12/1972"
    }

  ]

  angular.forEach($scope.people, function(value, key) {
    var dateParts = $scope.people[key].dob.split("/");
    var date = new Date(dateParts[2], (dateParts[1] - 1), dateParts[0]);
    $scope.people[key].dob = date;
  })

});
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">


  <!-- I want to put 2 people in a row. Then the next 2 people in a row... -->

  <div class="row" ng-repeat="person in people | orderBy:'-dob'">

    <div class="col col-50">
      <img ng-src="{{person.image}}">
      <p>{{person.dob | date : 'dd MMM yyyy'}}</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Here I want the next item in the array, not the same one. -->
    <div class="col col-50">
      <img ng-src="{{person.image}}">
      <p>{{person.dob | date : 'dd MMM yyyy'}}</p>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

I should probably mention I'm using ionic's grid. http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid

Comment: Why not just split after Every second item? Maybe something along the lines of: <div ng-if="$index % 2 == 0" class="clearfix"></div>.
You can use this in any way you like.

Comment: There is a variable called `$index` inside `ng-repeat`. You can take advantage of that, along with `ng-if` to conditionally output divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look to that [link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/grid-list-that-wraps-items/7658/3)

I guess you're using ionic based on `col col-50`.

```js
angular.module('starter', [])

.controller('PeopleCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.people = [

    {
      image: "https://placehold.it/350x150",
      dob: "23/06/1990"
    }, {
      image: "https://placehold.it/350x150",
      dob: "12/12/2000"
    }, {
      image: "https://placehold.it/350x150",
      dob: "12/12/1972"
    }

  ]

  angular.forEach($scope.people, function(value, key) {
    var dateParts = $scope.people[key].dob.split("/");
    var date = new Date(dateParts[2], (dateParts[1] - 1), dateParts[0]);
    $scope.people[key].dob = date;
  })

});
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>




</head>

<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">


  <!-- I want to put 2 people in a row. Then the next 2 people in a row... -->
  <div class="row" style="
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
">
  <div class="col col-50" ng-repeat="person in people | orderBy:'-dob'">

    <div >
      <img ng-src="{{person.image}}">
      <p>{{person.dob | date : 'dd MMM yyyy'}}</p>
    </div>

   

  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of going about this;

1.

```
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="person in people | orderBy:'-dob'">
      <div class="col col-50">
      <img ng-src="{{person.image}}">
      <p>{{person.dob | date : 'dd MMM yyyy'}}</p>
    </div>
    <div data-ng-show="$index % 2 == 0">My Seperator</div>
</div>
```

or:

```
<br ng-if="!(($index + 1) % 2)" />
```

or with css:

```
<div class="section">
    <div ng-repeat="person in people | orderBy:'-dob'">
      <img ng-src="{{person.image}}">
      <p>{{person.dob | date : 'dd MMM yyyy'}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>

.section > div:nth-of-type(2n+1){
  clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just give the div's containing the col, a col of 6, it will add up to 12 (bootstrap's max width) and start a new row.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the object before you display it.  It's a little hacky and I don't recommend it.  Maybe someone with more experience in CSS can recommend a pure CSS version.

```
//put two people per array inside $scope.people
$scope.people2 = [];
while($scope.people.length) {
    $scope.people2.push($scope.people.splice(0,2));
}
```

Then in your HTML, you could do:

```
<div>
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="2people in people2">
        <div ng-repeat="person in 2people">{{person}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```